# Make rsync update existing files first, create new ones later?

Tags: rsync

I have a source directory which I'm periodically syncing to a target using rsync:

```
rsync --bwlimit=1600 --recursive --times
      --omit-dir-times --copy-links --modify-window=30
      --inplace --delete-before --progress --stats --whole-file
      --itemize-changes --human-readable ./ /media/0123-4567/
```

The target media is *just* the right size for the sync: the target is a 1000 MB partition, source has 990 MB of files; syncing from source to an empty target works fine.

The problem is when I'm syncing to a target which contains an older version: some of the existing source files are smaller in the current version, and some new are added. The total size stays 990 MB; but rsync seems to choose a strategy "copy new files first, then update the existing," the first part won't work, because the space that's supposed to be freed with the update is not there yet.

```
                                       version 1     version 2
 files not changed:                     800 MB        800 MB
 new files in v2:                         0 MB         80 MB
 files changed between versions:        190 MB        110 MB 

 total                                  990 MB        990 MB
```

In other words, how can I make rsync *update* the target first (which will, in my case, free up space), and only then *add new files*?

So far, I have hacked around this by having two separate invocations, only differing in this parameter:

```
rsync --existing [...]
rsync --ignore-existing [...]
```

This will update the existing files first, and copy the new ones later; Is there a way to do this with one command?

Comment: Note that there is similar functionality for files which don't exist in the new version: `--delete-before`; I haven't found any *`--update-before` or somesuch in the manpage.

Comment: Also, using a larger target partition is not possible (the target is not a common-off-the-shelf disk, I need to work with what I have).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So far, I have hacked around this by having two separate invocations,
>   only differing in this parameter:
>
> rsync --existing [...]
>   rsync --ignore-existing [...]

Yes, that's the correct way.

> This will update the existing files first, and copy the new ones
>   later; Is there a way to do this with one command?

No need:

- From speed perspective, you are only sacrificing some negligible overheads
- From documentation perspective, this is much clearer in stating what you are doing than some implicit ways.

Comment: Good points - the `stat` overhead for `--times` should be negligible; if I were using `--checksum`, it might have an effect.